# Why is the height of a 'div>a>img' larger than the size of the wrapped img?

Tags: css, dom

If I set the img's size to 100*100, the containing div will be like 100*106.

Where does that extra '6px' come from? How does this behavior fit to the standard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276

Answer (score 35, accepted):

@clyde; yes this is a natural behavior of image because img is an inline element so user agents leave some space for descender characters.

**you can remove it with css:**

```
img { display:block; } or img { vertical-align:bottom; }
```

**FOR MORE CHECK THESE**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

[Unwanted padding-bottom of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518576/unwanted-padding-bottom-of-a-div)

Comment: In addition, because the `img` element is inside an anchor (`a` element) it may have addional styles applied to it which cause the anchor to take more space than just the image alone. You may want to try `a img { border: none; } a:link {text-decoration: none; border: none}`.

Comment: Thanks! Space for descending characters in inline elements!

Comment: This was tripping me up this morning for far longer than I'd like to admit. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more code, especially CSS styles, but essentially the cascading part of CSS can easily flow inherited sizes downwards. If your A has a style of some extra padding or margin, then your final DIV will get it, too. And A is an inline element which often adds padding in anticipation of more content; turning A's to blocks often solves these kinds of issues, so I would try that first.